# TypeError in transform tensorflow model to onnx

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

I am new to deploy a tensorflow saved model to onnx model. When I am trying to transform the TensorFlow model to onnx using tf2onnx package, it comes out the following traceback:

```
"StatefulPartitionedCall/TransNet/ColorHistograms/UnsortedSegmentSum"
op: "UnsortedSegmentSum"
input: "StatefulPartitionedCall/TransNet/ColorHistograms/ones_like"
input: "StatefulPartitionedCall/TransNet/ColorHistograms/add_2"
input: "StatefulPartitionedCall/TransNet/ColorHistograms/mul_4"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tindices"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tnumsegments"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
, ex=value "<dtype: 'int32'>" is not valid attribute data type.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py", line 188, in <module>
    main()
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py", line 166, in main
    const_node_values=const_node_values)
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf2onnx/tfonnx.py", line 415, in process_tf_graph
    tensorflow_to_onnx(tf_graph, shape_override, const_node_values)
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_utils.py", line 375, in tensorflow_to_onnx
    return tflist_to_onnx(graph, shape_override, const_node_values)
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_utils.py", line 362, in tflist_to_onnx
    onnx_node = helper.make_node(node.type, input_names, output_names, name=node.name, **attr)
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnx/helper.py", line 110, in make_node
    for key, value in sorted(kwargs.items()))
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnx/helper.py", line 110, in <genexpr>
    for key, value in sorted(kwargs.items()))
  File "./opt/anaconda3/envs/finstocker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnx/helper.py", line 394, in make_attribute
    'value "{}" is not valid attribute data type.'.format(value))
TypeError: value "<dtype: 'int32'>" is not valid attribute data type.
```

I have checked the issues created in https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/362 and https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/184. However, it seems not any satisfied solutions. Wonder if any ideas could solve this problem, thanks so much.

Comment: Anywhere in your code did you typecast or specify dtype as `int32` instead of `tf.int32`?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will double check the type in the model.